# JavaFX действие при изменении значения переменной

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется label, на который выводится значение переменной a. Как реализовать автоматическое изменение информации на label при изменении a, чтобы не приходилось постоянно вызывать функцию setText в разных частях кода? Имеется ли какой-либо слушатель для этого или т.п.?

Comment: Объявите метод `setA`, а в нем вызывайте `setText`. А напрямую к переменной `a` не лезьте совсем

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Суть вопроса не в том, как сделать так, чтобы не трогать переменную а, а в том, чтобы не вызывать методы вообще, а был слушатель, который изменял бы все сам, при изменении значения переменной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контексте JavFX, только если `a` - это некое `javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue<?>`, необязательно `StringProperty`, тогда можно просто использовать бинды

```
SimpleDoubleProperty a = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
a.set(1.1d);

Label label = new Label();
label.textProperty().bind(a.asString());
```